# Logically let should have block scope, how this snippet is returning number?

Tags: javascript

```js
function fn() {
  let ax = bx = 110;
  ax++;
  return ax;
}
fn()
console.log(typeof bx)
console.log(typeof ax)
```

its answer is // undefined number .
I am very confused, how it is possible. as ax , bx is in scope

Comment: Actually `bx` is leaked to the global namespace here. You can't use this short-cut with `let`, `bx` is not declared at all, and a global variable will be created. Surely there's a duplicate for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we write `let ax = bx = 110;`, we are not doing

```
let ax = 110;
let bx = 110;
```

In fact there is no keyword in front of `bx`, and hence it is considered to be from the outer scope. In this case, `bx` becomes a part of global scope. And hence it is available outside.

PS:

One hacky way to do it in one line:

```js
function fn() {
  let [ax,bx] = [110,110];
  ax++;
  return ax;
}
fn()
console.log(typeof bx)
console.log(typeof ax)
```